# Имеются ли зависимости у .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Только разбираюсь с .Net-Core интересуюсь.\

1. Имеются ли изначально какие-либо зависимости в приложение на
   .Net-Core?
2. Net-Core это же получается Native уже на выходе?

Если запустить на чистой системе без установленного NetFramework'a, приложение запустится ? ( нет возможности проверить )

Comment: "Запустится" - и да и нет. Все зависит от того, как соберете.

Comment: чтобы проверить такие вещи, имеет смысл поставить виртуалку

Comment: .NET Core и .NET Framework - это разные технологии. Поэтому приложение Core может работать без FW. Однако, в любом случае нужен установленный рантайм.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можно же self-contained собрать

Comment: @yolosora - да, я неверно выразился. Но рантайм так или иначе нужен, просто он будет включён в состав самого экзешника.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Visual Studio** позволяет сделать `Self-contained` публикацию, которая будет включать в себя весь NET Core (ну или нужную его часть), при этом размер самого `.exe` файла увеличится до ~150 мегабайт, будет работать без уcтановленного .NET Core. В противном случае, требуется установка .NET Core Runtime.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- **Framework-dependent** - требуется установленный .NET Core
- **Self-contained** - не требуется

Подробности можно почитать по [этой ссылке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file).

Так же, **.NET Framework** и **.NET Core** Runtime - [разные дистрибутивы](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). Приложения, собранные под **Core** не будут работать, если установлен только **Framework**, и наоборот. Устанавливать можно и то и другое одновременно, дистрибутивы не конфликтуют.

*Net-Core это же получается Native уже на выходе?* - Нет. Такая фича называется Native Ahead-Of-Time (Native AOT) компиляция, **Microsoft** обещают сделать подобную возможность в **.NET 6**. (изначально [обещали](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) в .NET 5, но обещание не выполнили, чем [разгневали сообщество](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0-preview-7/#comment-6821)).

Comment: `Visual Studio позволяет сделать` - это позволяет сделать сам `.NET Core`, а студия лишь оболочка, удобный интерфейс) Также, если отвечать на `Если запустить на чистой системе без установленного NetFramework'a, приложение запустится?`, то можно сказать, что "ДА", ибо оно запустится и даст окно, где попросит установить `.NET Core`, с кнопкой, которая перекинет на нужную страницу загрузки. Ну и тут видно, что человек не понимает, что `Core` и `Framework` это две разные вещи. Может стоит указать про это все?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ последнее указал, остальное не считаю критичным.

Comment: Вот странно, в NET Framework получался вполне самодостаточный экзешник, и весил он всего 200 кБ, а тут при выборе Self-contained (если не выбрать опцию Produce Single File) в публикацию попадают вообще ненужные библиотеки, даже когда выбрана опция "Обрезать неиспользуемые сборки (в предварительной версии)". И да, получается под 150мБ. Существует ли какой-то действующий способ минифицировать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот именно, если NET Core не установлен, то приложение перекинет на страницу в инете, а не само установит. Это плохо с точки зрения дизайна приложения, особенно когда конечный пользователь - чайник, а таких большинство, какая-нибудь офисная блондинка

Comment: @PavelSumarokov `в NET Framework получался вполне самодостаточный экзешник`, который не мог без установленного .NET Framework работать? Это не самодостаточный. Здесь у вас в 150 мегов влезает полностью вся нужная часть .NET Core, и устанавливать в принципе ничего не нужно. А так, если вам нужно именно порадовать юзера удобной установкой, попробуйте установщик `ClickOnce`, он там же в окне `Publish` доступен. Но там есть свои нюансы, например нельзя выбрать каталог установки.

Comment: @aepot странно, но работало на другом компьютере, или что, NET Framework идёт с некоторыми конфигурациями Windows? И сейчас в этих 150М куча ненужных библиотек, например Visual Basic, которым я не пользовался в приложении

Comment: Странно, неужели вот это https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run не работает?

Comment: @VladD у автора имеется в виду компиляция в Native сборку (как C++). Быть может в ответе я не совсем точно выразился. Ready-to-run это по сути AOT, верно, но оно лишь оптимизирует скорость загрузки позволяя JIT использовать прекомпилированный код, а не компилировать IL в рантайме. А Native сборка, это когда JIT в принципе не нужен.

Comment: @aepot: Насколько я понимаю, R2R — это сразу нативный код, который может бежать и без JIT. У JIT есть tiered compilation, она может ещё больше соптимизировать (т. к. некоторые вещи известны лишь во время выполнения), и так и делает.

Comment: @VladD но это все равно не Native. Кстати, есть вот такой [форк](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/). Ну и [вот репозиторий](https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT), где в данный момент мелкомягкие трудятся над Native AOT

Comment: @aepot: А в чём именно заключается ненативность R2R? Метаданные в любом случае нужно включать, т. к. они могут понадобиться для рефлексии. Исходный IL-код generic-методов тоже необходим, т. к. мы не может в compile time знать размер такого объекта: `struct X<T> { T t; }`. А всё остальное по идее в R2R есть, верно?

Comment: @VladD если R2R - это нативная сборка, то почему пишут что CoreCLR не совместим с Native AOT в принципе, поэтому фичу пилят исключительно под CoreRT?

Comment: @aepot: Не знаю, если честно, это надо бы спросить у тех, кто пишет. Но вот первый же абзац из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/ready-to-run): "R2R is a form of ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation."

Comment: @VladD мы говорим о разных вещах, вы про AOT, а я про Native AOT. В терминологии Microsoft это 2 разные независимые фичи.

Comment: @aepot: А в чём реальная разница? Я не в курсе, в гугле за 5 минут не нашлось.

Comment: @VladD не прямой ответ, но можно [здесь почитать](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/form-factors.md#native-aot-form-factors).

Comment: @aepot: Ну там по сути пишут, что они хотят ещё быстрее старт, и ещё меньше размер бинарника. То есть по сути ещё более хороший AOT. Но как по мне, это вовсе не означает, что AOT (то есть, компиляции в нативный код) нет, согласны?

Comment: @VladD `Net-Core это же получается Native уже на выходе?` - вопрос от автора был такой. И так как R2R не исключает присутствия JIT в рантайме, ответ был "нет".

Comment: @aepot: Учитывая наличие в языке generic'ов, полностью исключить JIT из рантайма не удастся никогда. Поэтому разумно предположить, что JIT будет и в Native AOT (ну или некоторые конструкции языка будут падать, например, generic с незнакомым типом параметров или dynamic).

Comment: @VladD значит ответа "да" не будет никогда. :)

Comment: @aepot: Мне кажется, вы даёте слишком строгие критерии «нативности». Но это уже авторские предпочтения, конечно.