# Как скомпилировать единый exe файл в проекте Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5

Сохраняется вот так, как можно создать единый файл?

[image]

Comment: @AK Я не согласен с тем, что прилинкованный ответ отвечает на вопрос, поскольку это .NET Core/5, а ответ для Framework.

Comment: @aepot Действительно, ловите плюсик за внимательность к деталям.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вам нужно опубликовать **Build -> Publish** приложение, в параметрах публикации выбрать **Folder**, далее выбрать **win-x64** файл и поставить галочку **Produce single file**.

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#publish-a-single-file-app---visual-studio)

> #### Публикация приложения с одним файлом с помощью Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio создает многократно используемые профили публикации, которые управляют процессом публикации приложения.
>
> 1. В обозревателе решений щелкните правой кнопкой мыши проект, который нужно опубликовать. Нажмите кнопку **Опубликовать**.
>    [image: Обозреватель решений с контекстным меню, где выделен пункт Опубликовать]
>    Если у вас еще нет профиля публикации, следуйте инструкциям по его созданию и выберите **Папка** в качестве типа целевого объекта.
> 2. Нажмите кнопку **Изменить**.
>    [image: Профиль публикации Visual Studio с кнопкой Изменить]
> 3. В диалоговом окне **Параметры профиля** задайте следующие параметры.
>
>    - Параметру **Режим развертывания** задайте значение **Автономное** или **Зависимое от платформы**.
>    - В качестве значения параметра **Целевая среда выполнения** укажите платформу, на которую будет выполнена публикация. (Значение должно быть отличным от **Переносимый**.)
>    - Выберите **Создать отдельный файл**.
>      Нажмите кнопку **Сохранить**, чтобы сохранить параметры и вернуться в диалоговое окно **Публикация**.
>      [image: Диалоговое окно параметров профиля с выделенными параметрами для режима развертывания, целевой среды выполнения и создания отдельного файла]
> 4. Чтобы опубликовать приложение с одним файлом, нажмите кнопку **Опубликовать**.
>
> Дополнительные сведения см. в статье [Публикация приложений .NET Core с помощью Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs).

По поводу того, чем опции **Self-contained** и **Framework-dependent** отличаются, я ранее рассказывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1177095/373567).

Если все прошло хорошо, профиль публикации **Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml** будет выглядеть вот так

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\Publish</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>True</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

А в интерфейсе публикации оно будет выглядеть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Примечание для .NET 5 и более новых версий

Так как в .NET 5 оптимизировали технологию запуска приложения из одиночного файла, теперь по умолчанию он не включает в себя нативные библиотеки, а включает только управляемые.

Если ваша сборка зависит от нативных библиотек, и вы столкнулись с тем, что dll файлы при публикации все равно лежат отдельно, то чтобы это вылечить, в первую секцию `<PropertyGroup>` **.cproj** файла нужно добавить опцию:

```xml
<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124299/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot----exe----visua).