# Как использовать сторонние библиотеки (например nuget), что бы не оставлять их в папке с exe

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

У меня есть приложение которое использует библиотеку из nuget, при компиляции эта библиотека помещается в папку сборки проекта, и если вытащить библиотеку от туда приложение начинает работать не корректно. Можно ли каким то образом использовать эту библиотеку, при том что она не будет лежать в папке с исполняемым файлом?

Если нельзя, то объясните как действовать в таких случаях, и как это делают в больших проектах.

Comment: И в чем проблема оставить библиотеку? В больших проектах оставляют, зайдите в папку с любой "большой" программой - там будет куча dll-ок.

Comment: Можно собрать приложение так, чтобы эта библиотека встроилась в исполняемый файл. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567

Comment: если windows, можете использовать WinAPI функцию `AddDllDirectory`