# Не запускается скомпилированный *.exe без файла runtimeconfig.json, runtimeconfig.dev.json, deps.json

Tags: c#, exe, .net-5

Написал очень важную программу (.NET 5), скомпилировал - всё работает идеально. Скинул *.exe файл другу (у него установелен .NET 5) - не запускается без трёх файлов:

1. `MyProject.runtimeconfig.json`
2. `MyProject.runtimeconfig.dev.json`
3. `MyProject.deps.json`

Если удалить первый файл то получаю следущую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если удалить 2, 3 файл то никаких ошибок не получаю, но и экзешник не запускается.

**Вопрос**: как мне без всяких непонятных зависимостей запустить файл на другом ПК?

Comment: пробовали настраивать cspoj файл? <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>false</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>  тут подробно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029100

Comment: ПКМ по проекту - Публикация - Настраиваете все на единый файл, получаете один .exe.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я сделал `self-contained`. Не запускается

Comment: Ну, вы сами ведь понимаете, что "Не запускается", это для программиста не объяснение. Значит у вас не установлен допустим .NET Runtime. А так, это [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ всё установлено и всё работает. Как оказывается, просто я забыл добавить текстовичок рядом с экзешником с которым работает программа