# Не получается "секлеить" dll

Tags: c#, windows, dll, exe

При попытке склеить dll через ilmerge происходит исключение

```
An exception occurred during merging:
Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: WindowsBase.
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitField(Field field)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.Visit(Node node)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.Visit(Node node)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
   в System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)
   в System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delaySign, String keyFileName, String keyName)
   в System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters, Module module)
   в System.Compiler.Module.WriteModule(String location, CompilerParameters options)
   в ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()
   в ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)
```

пробовал вручную указывать путь к .net но не помогло, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Версия дотнета какая?

Comment: v4.0.30319, и 6

Comment: на .NET 6 ILMerge не будет работать и не должен, и не нужен он там https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567

Comment: а что делать, я пробовал указать вручную но не помогло

Comment: @aepot, когда нажимаю опубликовать, открывается мастер публикации, нету профиля

Comment: если что у меня wpf приложение

Comment: так создайте профиль