# Зашифровать WPF .Net 6 *.dll

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, криптография, шифрование

Необходим шифровщик/криптер для сокрытия исходного кода и ресурсов WPF .Net 6 приложения (не обфускация).
Криптостойкость не имеет особого значения, главное чтобы декомпилятор, вроде dotPeek, не отображал код и ресурсы. Ну, и чтобы шифровка не поломала само приложение.
Бесплатный, платный, с подпиской или может даже спеца кто может посоветовать.

Comment: А как вы планируете это расшифровывать? Даже если получится, что мне мешает отладчик в загруженной либе подцепить и стащить все тот же код? Защита от дурака, не более. Берите обычный AES. Кстати, а где ключ шифрования будете хранить? Тоже ничто не мешает мне взять ключ из открытой части исходников и все расшифровать. И последний прикол - если исходники не будут подписаны сертификатом безопасности, ваше приложение тут же будет сожрано первым попашимся антивирусом. Так себе идея.

Comment: Собирать в [единый файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567) все ресурсы пробовали? Вроде dotpeek не цепляется к такой сборке, потому что снаружи она нативная. Но надежность защиты от подцепиться к сборке отладчиком такая же как у шифрования с ключом, спрятанным в коде, то есть никакая. Хотите по-настоящему спрятать код - уносите его на сервер, и работайте с ним через API с авторизацией.

Comment: под шифровкой имел ввиду упаковщик, который во время запуска извлекает приложение и выполняет (в идеале) в памяти. по поводу криптостойкости писал в первом сообщении. так как и о главной цели (сокрытии от dotPeek и аналогов). мне главное заказчику показать что типа защита кода есть, а об альтернативах он, скорее всего, не знает.

Comment: Ну соберите в единый файл и проверьте

Comment: собирал. dotPeek разбирает

Comment: Окей, вам нужно какую-то критическу библиотеку спрятать, или вообще всё? Последнее невозможно, совсем.