# Как скомпилировать срр файл в ехе чтобы он запускался без консоли? Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как скомпилировать срр файл в ехе чтобы он запускался без консоли как процесс?
использую Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Проще всего — сделайте обычное консольное приложение и натравите на него после компиляции `editbin /subsystem:windows filename.exe`...

Comment: А можно указать `/subsystem:windows` сразу при сборке приложения...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282216/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-exe-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-visual-studio Возможно, это вам поможет

Comment: @KiraBoB По ссылке левый вопрос, причем по c#

Comment: @KiraBoB там просто компиляция в ехе с консолью а мне надо чтоб когда я запускал этот ехешник консоль не открывалась

Comment: @user7860670 А он не захочет при этом `WinMain()`, а не `main()`?

Comment: @Harry Естественно ожидать от неконсольного приложения использования `WinMain`