# Как распаковать lzma-архив

Tags: c#, winforms

C# 10, WinForms, есть lzma-архив. Задача распаковать его. Знаю про SevenZip. Но как его использовать?

Comment: Как задать хороший вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Здесь помогают решить задачу а не решают за других. Нужны хотя бы какие-то попытки сделать самому и описание что конкретно не получилось

Comment: Почему вы хотите сделать это именно из C#? Ведь это возможно с помощью обычного архиватора.

Comment: Потому что есть архив с данными для программы и его надо извлечь))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл пакет [SevenZipExtractor](https://github.com/adoconnection/SevenZipExtractor). Любой архив можно распаковать с помощью кода:

```
using (ArchiveFile archiveFile = new (@"<ЗДЕСЬ ПУТЬ И ИМЯ АРХИВА>"));
archiveFile.Extract("<ЗДЕСЬ ПАПКА, КУДА ИЗВЛЕКАТЬ>");
```

Единственный минус -- таскает с собой библиотеку 7za.dll двух разрядностей, но с этим можно смирится.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567 - вдруг пригодится