# Публикация приложения в программе C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, .net-7

Как мне опубликовать приложение? При опубликации выдает какого-то **Мастер Приложении**. После его компиляция он уже похож будто это запись на диск или ещё куда-то...

Использую: Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Какая версия дотнета?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567

Comment: Версия дотнета - 7.0.201

Comment: У меня там другое окно появляется. Мастер публикации

Comment: Ну и выбирайте публикацию в папку (folder)