Как скомпилировать json файлы(либо другие файлы) в один exe с помощью Costura.fody, C#
У меня есть WPF проект, в него я вставил json файл(он у меня только для просмотра), который компилируется в папку Debug. Установил Costura.fody, так как мне нужно, что бы приложение компилировалось в один exe.
Проблема в том, что Costura.fody собирает все файлы в один exe, кроме того самого json файла.
Что можно сделать что-бы внедрить json в один exe? Смогу ли я его просматривать? И есть ли примеры с другими файлами, например .txt файлы?

Файл ресурсов сделай

Начиная с .NET Core можно собирать что угодно в один файл без сторонних библиотек. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282220/373567

Очень интересно. Конечно, использовать именно Costura.fody имеет смысл только под винду и NET Framework 4.8, дальше - как aepot написал. Но навскидку - я поискал, не пишут, как пользовательские файлы добавлять в сборку

Вообще, если речь не о встраивании библиотек в один экзешник, а о ресурсах, их можно в любом дотнете вшить. Это же просто ресурсы https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0

Да.. Приложение на NET Framework. Всем спасибо за помощь
