# Как хранить c# программу в разных файлах

Tags: c#, visual-studio

подскажите как хранить программу C# в Visul studio по разным файлам(ООП каждый класс в отдельном файле). И как избежать проблемы(если такие будут) при компиляции одной программы в один файл .exe? То есть как создать файл в этой же директории(отдельный класс). Нужно ли будет в каждой файле подключать классы которые нужны? (Можно ли вынести это в отдельный файл и подключать его).

Comment: Создаётся тут-же вопрос, зачем? Зачем этот лишний геморрой с кучей файлов? А если по факту - то весь CSharp это набор таких самых библиотек. Называется это дело Class Library и создаётся прям в Solution файлах https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/creating-and-using-dll-class-library-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: В Visual Studio есть возможность смотреть используемые файлы всего проекта. Чтобы открыть это окно необходимо перейти в меню "Вид" -> "Обозреватель решений". В нем Вы можете добавлять папки или файлы. Для подключения своих классов используйте ключевое слово ```using namespace_вашего_файла```. После компиляции программы через VS в папке ```bin\debug``` будет ```ВашПроектНейм.exe``` файл, который вы и можете запускать (если необходимы какие-либо dll для работы с файлом, они так же будут лежать в одной директории)

Comment: Создайте проект в Visual Studio, добавляйте в него сколько угодно файлов, проект соберется в один. Чтобы разбить решение по сборкам (dll), нужно на каждую библиотеку создавать отдельный проект.

Comment: @EugeneX `лишний геморой?` А как вы предлагаете? хранить все классы в одном файле?

Comment: 1 файл - 1 класс. На собранный проект разбитие C# кода на файлы никак не влияет. Я вообще недоумеваю, откуда ваш вопрос взялся, ведь проблемы, о которой вы пишете, на самом деле нет. Нужен конкретный пример, как ее воспроизвести. Ведь чтобы что-то исправить - надо видеть, что сломалось.

Comment: @aepot именно так я и хочу, просто большой вопрос был как раз с использованием `Using clasname`. Хотелось всё зависимости вынести ещё в один отдельный файл, а потом этот файл подключать в начале каждого файла

Comment: Создайте файл, там где строка namespace будет название соответствующего namespace'а. Его и используйте при подключении через using

Comment: @aepot ничего не ломалось, как раз спрашиваю, чтобы потом ничего не ломалось)

Comment: С помощью using подключаются не файлы, а неймспейсы. В одном неймспейсе может быть много классов, а при условии "1 файл - 1 класс", следует, что в 1 неймспейсе может быть много файлов. Это нормально. Ну вы попробуйте, поэкспериментируйте, нормально оно работает.

Comment: Структурно - одна папка с cs файлами = 1 неймспейс.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю, за ответы. Просто я PHP-шник(

Comment: Плюсом у меня  WPF project и получается что под каждым файлом .xaml свой файл .cs

Comment: @artemgh тогда сразу скажу, что конкатенация строк через `+` в шарпе, а не через `.` :)

Comment: @artemgh это студия вам показывает как cs под xaml, для удобства, на самом деле это 2 разных файла, лежащих просто рядом в одной папке.

Comment: @aepot `тогда сразу скажу, что конкатенация строк через + в шарпе, а не через . :)`. Ахаха, да спасибо, хотя для меня всегда было "+" и это было вопросом при переходе на PHP)

Comment: Если речь про WPF - начните копать в сторону шаблона проектирования MVVM. Там будет очень много ответов на вопросы о структуре приложения.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо, подытожите всё в одном ответе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скомпилирую свои комменты в ответ.

Создайте проект в Visual Studio, добавляйте в него сколько угодно файлов, проект соберется в один исполняемый модуль (exe файл например). Чтобы разбить решение по сборкам (dll), нужно на каждую библиотеку создавать отдельный проект.

1 файл - 1 класс. На собранный проект разбитие C# кода на файлы никак не влияет. Я вообще недоумеваю, откуда ваш вопрос взялся, ведь проблемы, о которой вы пишете, на самом деле нет. Нужен конкретный пример, как ее воспроизвести. Ведь чтобы что-то исправить - надо видеть, что сломалось.

С помощью `using` подключаются не файлы, а неймспейсы. В одном неймспейсе может быть много классов, а при условии "1 файл - 1 класс", следует, что в 1 неймспейсе может быть много файлов. Это нормально. Ну вы попробуйте, поэкспериментируйте, нормально оно работает.

Если речь про WPF - начните копать в сторону шаблона проектирования MVVM. Там будет очень много ответов на вопросы о структуре приложения.

Материалы по теме

- [Как скомпилировать единый exe файл в проекте Visual Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1282216/373567)
- [Имеются ли зависимости у .Net Core?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1177077/373567)

Comment: Всё оказалось, ещё проще, просто создаешь новый элемент -> Класс. И он сам всё прописывает, Visual studio классная штука, причем класса задаётся как internal

Comment: Тем не менее огромное спасибо, за MVVM. На хабре пару статей нашёл, полезно для понимания незнакомого инструмента

Comment: @artemgh я про это и говорил, что там париться не надо об этом вопросе. А мощь WPF - да, раскрывается когда въезжаешь в смысл привязок данных и MVVM. Хотя-бы [вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567).

Comment: просто после написания кода в Sublime text и запуске его потом вручную, отвыкаешь надеяться на IDE)