# Предупреждения CA1416 после апгрейда проекта с NET Framework до NET 8

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8

Сделал апгрейд проекта с NET Framework до NET 8 и получил огромное количество предупреждений с кодом CA1416
`CA1416 Этот сайт вызова доступен на всех платформах. "BarItem.Enabled" поддерживается только в 'windows'`

В настройках проекта выбрана целевая ОС Windows, поэтому кроссплатформенность не используется, соответственно и предупреждения вроде бы не должны выводиться. Если создать новый проект, то подобные предупреждения не появляются.
Как задать настройки проекта, что приложение только для Windows, чтобы убрать эти предупреждения? Про то, что их можно скрыть знаю, но хочу попробовать корректно настроить параметры проекта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .csproj файле установите TargetFramework = `net8-windows` и пересоберите проект (Rebuild).

Если пересборка не помогает, закройте студию, удалите в папке с проектом папки bin и obj, запустите и снова пересоберите.

- [Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms)

---

Обратите внимание, что в новом .NET рабочая версия приложения формируется не через сборку (Build), а через публикацию в папку (Publish).

- [Как скомпилировать единый exe файл в проекте Visual Studio?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1282216/373567)
- [Имеются ли зависимости у .Net Core?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1177077/373567)

Comment: Ещё есть опция "Очистить решение", иногда и она помогает )